# How can i invoke another jenkins build job from groovy script

Tags: jenkins

I want to invoke another Jenkins build job through groovy  , How I can do that . I tried with including like below but no luck

```
build 'job url'
```

but got the error

> ERROR: No parameterized job named

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're talking about [jenkins-pipeline](/questions/tagged/jenkins-pipeline)'s [`build`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job) step, right?

This takes the job name as parameter, not a URL. So to trigger a job called *test*, use

```
build 'test'
```

It seems searching for a parameterized job, maybe because you gave multiple arguments? Please be more precise with your example code and what the job name is (is it in another folder)?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Pipeline Plugin and you want to build a parametrized job you can do:

Supose you have a "sonar-review" boolean parameter:

```
build job: 'cargo-pipeline-ci-declarative', parameters: [booleanParam(name: 'sonar-review', value: false)]
```

In case you aren't required to build a job with parameters:

You can just do:

```
build "cargo-pipeline-ci-declarative"
```

Be sure you have installed:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for your response - build ''cargo-pipeline-ci-declarative''  worked for me

Comment: Why the double single quotes?

Comment: What if the job is sorted in a subdirectory, you know like `/job/mydirectory/job/myjob` ?

Comment: @Sandburg then the name has to be "mydirectory/myjob"

Answer (score 2):

If you truly just want to fire a job by the URL you can do so using by posting to

```
http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=Value
```

see [parameterized-builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) for details.

As far as through groovy there are several ways to do this. Since you asked specifically with groovy see the [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkinsci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) which provides an example on how to trigger another build.

You can also use the [jobs-dsl-plugin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/) as well.  But that is being phased out by the pipeline workflow.

As such I would recommend to use the [multibranch pipeline plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/) which allows you to write your pipeline as code in a [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) and builds will automatically trigger for any branch in your repository.  Just simply create a multibranch pipeline job and set your SCM to your repository.  Then any branch with a Jenkinsfile in the root of the project will automatically build.

A benefit to using the multibranch pipeline plugin is that it provides the [snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) which will generate the code for you. This is helpful in learning the syntax and how to write code yourself.

Finally, to address your actual issue.  You don't provide a url but the name of the job you want to trigger.

You also need to consider the defaults. For example, below I'm triggering a job called `jobName` which will wait 10 seconds before starting `jobName`, my upstream job will not fail even if the triggered job does, and my upstream job will not wait for the triggered job to finish before marking itself complete. Again, see the snippet generator for details.

```
build job: 'jobName', propagate: false, quietPeriod: 10, wait: false
```